# Best way to train a model having train/test/val set

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, validation, lstm, pre-training

I'm new in the machine learning field and I'm trying to understand what are the best practices to manipulate the time series. I currently have a dataset structured as well:

1. **X0**: the first part of my time series where there are no anomaly values. I have *x0_train* which is the train set, *x0_test* which is the test set and *x0_val* which is the validation set. These three portions have no anomalies.
2. **X1**: the second part of the time series, where all the values are anomaly. I only have *x1_val* and *x1_test*
3. **X2**: the third part of the, where all the values are anomaly too, like X1. Again, I only have *x2_val* and *x2_test*.

These micro datasets are a time series. The order of them in the time series is:

`X0train - X0val - X1val - X2val - X0test - X1test - X2test`

I need to train a model (LSTM) and make a prediction on all the 5 parts of the dataset, so the final code will be:

```python
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath=filepath_model)
X0train_seq_pred = model.predict(X0train_seq) # X0train
X0test_seq_pred = model.predict(X0test_seq) # X0test
X0val_seq_pred = model.predict(X0val_seq) # X0val
X1test_seq_pred = model.predict(X1test_seq) # X1test
X1val_seq_pred = model.predict(X1val_seq) #X1val
X2test_seq_pred = model.predict(X2test_seq) #X2test
X2val_seq_pred = model.predict(X2val_seq) #X2val
```

My question is: how do I train it? Only on *x0_train* splitting it 80% in training and 20% in validation? Or should I use one of the validation set? If yes, which one? Two of them (X1, X2) are full of anomalies, so my fear is that the final model underfit/overfit if trained on the wrong validation set.